# How to add EJS code to jquery append function?

Tags: jquery, node.js, append, ejs

I have problem. I have dynamic form, with  and I need to looping  with data from database.

I have this on first row:

```
 <select class="form-select" id="serviceName1" onchange="getServiceInfo('1')" name="serviceName">
                        <option selected value="none">Wybierz pozycję</option>
                        <% invServices.forEach(invServices => { %>
                          <option><%= invServices.services.name %></option>
                        <% }); %>
                      </select>
```

And this to copy:

```
$(wrapper).append(
                 "<select id='serviceName"+x+"' class='form-select' name='serviceName'>"+
                    "<option selected value='none'>Wybierz pozycję</option>"+
                     '<% invServices.forEach(invServices => { %>'+
                        "<option><%= invServices.services.name %></option>"+
                        "<% }); %>'"+
                    "</select>"+    )
```

And this copy part <%= blah blah blah%>, rendering like string on my page.

Can i using this tags <%%> with jquery append? Or mayby someone have any better way to do dynamic forms?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

To do this from the front-end (which I assume is what you're asking because you're asking about inserting with jQuery), the steps are as follows:

1. Create a mini EJS template (which it looks like you already have).
2. Get the data from the database (probably with an Ajax call to your back-end server if you don't already have the data in the web page).
3. Import the EJS client-side library so it is available for client use.
4. Then, call EJS `ejs.render()` passing it the template and the data to use for that template to generate HTML with the data inserted.
5. Then, use jQuery to insert that generated HTML into your existing page where you want it.

Alternately, you could create a single Ajax call that does steps 1-4 on the server and returns generated HTML for you and then you insert that generated HTML that the Ajax call returns into your page where you want it.